# Android Intent-filter working for Magic, but no Hero, what could be the issue?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I'm working on an application that got an activity that is set to have intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.RINGTONE_PICKER"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This works fine when im testing with a HTC Magic phone, when I go to settings -> set ringtone, i get to choose from my app or the built in ringtone picker... But on Hero it goes directly to the build in picker...

Anyone got any idea on what the problem could be?

Comment: Perhaps you have, at some earlier point, been prompted on your hero about how to handle that intent, and selected the "Don't ask again" option...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for response, but we already found a way... to add another intent-filter... seems like HTC Hero uses a HTC_RINGTONE_PICKER intent insted of RINGTONE_PICKER intent...